# PHP Sending Large Amounts of Email to Amazon SES

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, phpmailer, amazon-ses

I have an online software that sends emails to Amazon SES. Currently I have a cron job that sends the emails via the SMTP with phpmailer to send the messages. Currently I have to max the send limit to around 300 every minute to make sure my server doesn't time out. We see growth and eventually I'd like to send out to 10,000 or more.

Is there a better way to send to Amazon SES, or is this what everyone else does, but with just more servers running the workload?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can try using the AWS SDK for PHP. You can send emails through the SES API, and the SDK allows you to send multiple emails in parallel. Here is a code sample (untested and only partially complete) to get you started.

```
<?php

require 'vendor/autoload.php';

use Aws\Ses\SesClient;
use Guzzle\Service\Exception\CommandTransferException;

$ses = SesClient::factory(/* ...credentials... */);

$emails = array();
// @TODO SOME SORT OF LOGIC THAT POPULATES THE ABOVE ARRAY

$emailBatch = new SplQueue();
$emailBatch->setIteratorMode(SplQueue::IT_MODE_DELETE);

while ($emails) {
    // Generate SendEmail commands to batch
    foreach ($emails as $email) {
        $emailCommand = $ses->getCommand('SendEmail', array(
            // GENERATE COMMAND PARAMS FROM THE $email DATA
        ));
        $emailBatch->enqueue($emailCommand);
    }

    try {
        // Send the batch
        $successfulCommands = $ses->execute(iterator_to_array($emailBatch));
    } catch (CommandTransferException $e) {
        $successfulCommands = $e->getSuccessfulCommands();
        // Requeue failed commands
        foreach ($e->getFailedCommands() as $failedCommand) {
            $emailBatch->enqueue($failedCommand);
        }
    }

    foreach ($successfulCommands as $command) {
        echo 'Sent message: ' . $command->getResult()->get('MessageId') . "\n";
    }
}

// Also Licensed under version 2.0 of the Apache License.
```

You could also look into using the [Guzzle `BatchBuilder` and friends](http://guzzlephp.org/batching/batching.html#batching-overview) to make it more robust.

There are a lot of things you will need to fine tune with this code, but you *may* be able to achieve higher throughput of emails.

Answer (score 2):

If anyone is looking for this answer, its outdated and you can find the new documentation here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-sdk-php/v3/guide/guide/commands.html

```
use Aws\S3\S3Client;
use Aws\CommandPool;

// Create the client.
$client = new S3Client([
    'region'  => 'us-standard',
    'version' => '2006-03-01'
]);

$bucket = 'example';
$commands = [
    $client->getCommand('HeadObject', ['Bucket' => $bucket, 'Key' => 'a']),
    $client->getCommand('HeadObject', ['Bucket' => $bucket, 'Key' => 'b']),
    $client->getCommand('HeadObject', ['Bucket' => $bucket, 'Key' => 'c'])
];

$pool = new CommandPool($client, $commands);

// Initiate the pool transfers
$promise = $pool->promise();

// Force the pool to complete synchronously
$promise->wait();
```

Same thing can be done for SES commands

Comment: Thank you for posting this. I used your code here and it sped up my project considerably. I am using AWS to queue up emails in a SQS (queue) and then send with SES (simple email service). For 3500 emails, SQS->sendMessage takes 57s, SQS->sendMessageBatch takes 14s, and SQS->sendMessage + CommandPool takes 4s. Big improvement!

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your answer. It was a good starting point. @Jeremy Lindblom

My problem is now that i can't get the Error-Handling to work.
The catch()-Block works fine and inside of it

```
$successfulCommands
```

returns all the succeed Responses with Status-Codes, but only if an error occurs. For example "unverified address" in Sandbox-Mode. Like a catch() should work. :)

The **$successfulCommands** inside the try-Block only returns:

```
SplQueue Object
(
    [flags:SplDoublyLinkedList:private] => 1
    [dllist:SplDoublyLinkedList:private] => Array
    (
    )
)
```

I can't figure it out how to get the real Response from Amazon with Status-Codes etc.

Comment: The `execute()` method basically returns whatever iterable data structure that was passed in, but with the command objects updated to reflect their execution. Since `SqlQueue::IT_DELETE_MODE` is enabled, it removed the commands from the `SqlQueue` (which is the iterable data structure in this case), causing them not to be returned. I have edited my original code sample to add a call to `iterator_to_array()` which should fix it. It should now iterate through the queue as before, but store the commands in an array, which will be returned by `execute` with all the command objects present.

Comment: Thank you Jeremy! iterator_to_array() does the trick and now i can get the response from amazon inside the try-Block! You're my man! :)